# C++: Bitshifting an unsigned short

Tags: c++, unsigned, short

I'm trying to save 2 unsigned char into a single unsigned short.
So what I do is save the 1st char, bitshift it then OR with the 2nd char.

Code:

```
unsigned char a = 8;
unsigned char b = 2;
unsigned short c = a;
c << 8;
c |= b;
```

But I have a problem with the bitshift first.
Running this code:

```
unsigned char a = 8;
unsigned short c = a;
c << 8;
cout << c;
```

I would expect to get 2048.
I even checked here: http://www.miniwebtool.com/bitwise-calculator/bit-shift/?data_type=10&number=8&place=8&operator=Shift+Left. 
But instead I get 8. What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

```
c <<= 8;
```

not

```
c << 8;
```

The second case doesn't modify the value of c. I would have expected your compiler to warn you about that.

Comment: No problem, I've made the same mistake as well.